# ajax JSON request to the server type=POST(secure log in request)

Tags: php, json

To submit via JavaScript plain - not jQuery...
ajax JSON request to the server type=POST(secure log in request) required web form?

how do it without a web form ... where put the JSON sent string var and by how/what get in php?

ajax3.send(jsonStringhere);  // ??? how get the in php???

```
function loginProcess() {
var userID = document.getElementById( "name" ).value;
var email = document.getElementById( "email" ).value;
var password = document.getElementById( "password" ).value;

ajax3 = new XMLHttpRequest();

//1st way
ajax3.open("GET","loginProcess.php?userID="+userID+"&email="+email+"&password="+password,false); 
ajax3.addEventListener("readystatechange", processResponse, true); 
ajax3.send();

changeDisplay("loginRegisterDiv");


//2nd way JSON post type here

//???

}
```

Comment: I'll vote-up any answer from the person who understood anything that even remotely nears the OPs question ..

Answer (score 2):

You should not be sending sensitive information like that via the URL (GET).

People often share URLs and probably don't want their personal information hidden within.

To simulate a web form, try sending a POST request. Put the JSON in a query attribute:

```
var ec = window.encodeURIComponent,
    queryStr = "userID=" + ec(userID) + "&email=" + ec(email) + "&password=" + ec(password) + "&json" + ec(JSON.stringify(yourJson)),
    ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajaxReq.open("POST", "loginProcess.php", false);  // Should really be 'true' for asynchronous...
ajaxReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');  // Important!
ajaxReq.send(queryStr);
```

Comment: You need to URL-encode all the parameters (in case the password or JSON contains `&`).